# How to overwrite eigenclass method in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a module

```
module A
  class << self
    def is_okay?; false; end
  end
end
```

and I need to overwrite `is_okay?` method in another module. Module `B` is included into `A` in this way

```
A.send(:include, B)
```

I have tried this

```
module B
  class << self
    def is_okay?; true; end
  end
end
```

and that

```
module B
  def self.is_okay?; true; end
end
```

but it didn't work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: when you say `it didn't work` what exactly do you mean? show how you are testing it.

Comment: You are confusing `include` with inheritance. You could use alias to achieve what you want, but simply including is not going to work as you have discovered.

Comment: `B::is_okay?` is defined in `B`s eigenclass and `A::is_okay?` is defined in `A`s eigenclass. `including` `B` in `A` does not change this at all (or anything really)

Comment: Should clarify here that "A" is not your module, and is not within your code base. That would also explain the unconventional use of "send" to include your module, which is not even necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not work in your situation:

```
module B
  def is_okay?
    true
  end
end

module A

  class << self

    prepend B

    def is_okay?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

`prepend` is similar to `include`, but inserts itself *before* the class, at the "bottom" of the ancestor chain.

**EDIT:**

Since you clarified in your comments below (I would suggest clarifying your original question), you can alias the same as any other method.

```
module A

  class << self
    alias original_is_okay? is_okay?
    def is_okay?
      true
    end

  end
end
```

This will allow for "overwriting it, whether or not you have access to it.

Comment: I can't change module A. I want to overwrite it by module B.

Comment: If you tested the above, you would see that if you called `A.is_okay?`, the return value is `true`, being called from `B`, not `false` as it is defined in `A`. Is that not the intended behavior?

Comment: Sure, but I can't modify `A`. `A` must remain unchanged.

Comment: I don't think you understand what include even does then, or why you are even using it within A. By default, including B into A with the same method leaves it unchanged. `A.is_okay?` will still return `false`. It is unmodified. You are asking how to overwrite something but leave it unchanged. Just alias it if that is the desired behavior, I have no clue what all this `include` and eigenclass and B module stuff is even about then. The original code you posted doesn't override "is_okay?" in either A or B, yet you include it in A, saying you want to overwrite, but then say it can't be changed...

Comment: To be clear. `A` is defined in another repository that I don't have access, so I can't modify `A`. I can't use `prepend` inside `A`. There is a `is_okay?` method that returns `false`. I want to overwrite this method to return `true` somehow. So, I want call `A.is_okay?` and I expect `true`.

Comment: First, you *can* modify it whether or not in its another repository, just re-open the class and add/modify whatever you want, so long as you load the original before attempting to add to it. I updated my answer to show how. Technically you could just re-define the method without an alias, but I used an alias to maintain the original behavior if you still required it. Would just have to call `A.original_is_okay?` to get the "unmodified" version.

Comment: @engineersmnky For straight redefinition, yes, don't think that works with aliasing, though.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 I guess you could go with `singleton_class.alias_method :original_is_okay?, :is_okay?` and still redefine `is_okay?` directly in `A`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
module B
  def bi
    "hello from bi"
  end
  def self.bm
    "hello from bm"
  end
end

B.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:bi]
B.methods(false)
  #=> [:bm]
```

Note that defining a module method (here `bm`) with `self.` is the same as defining an instance method on the module's singleton class.

Now create a module `A` that includes `B`.

```
module A
  def self.am
    "hello from am"
  end
end

A.methods(false)
  #=> [:am]
A.include B

A.instance_methods.include?(:bi)
  #=> true
A.methods.include?(:bm)
  #=> false
```

As expected, `bi` is now an instance method of `A`. `include`, however, disregards module methods, here `B::bm`. Is there any way for the module method `B::m` to become a module method of `A`? The answer is "no". In effect, we want

```
A.singleton_class.include B.singleton_class
```

but that doesn't work because `B.singleton_class` is a class.

[Module#include](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-include) does not make it clear whether a module (that is possibly a class) can include a class. Try it, however, and you will see the following an exception is raised:

```
TypeError (wrong argument type Class (expected Module))
```

If module methods of a module `M` are not made available to another module that includes `M`, is there any reason for modules to have module methods? Yes, to provide libraries of methods! An example is the module [Math](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Math.html). That module contains many module methods and no instance methods. When used, those methods are  therefore invoked on their receiver, `Math`. For example,

```
Math.sin(x)
```